# How can we take user inputs in azure runbooks using powershell? does It supports user interaction?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-automation, redirect-uri, azure-app-registration

I have a PS script that register's an app in Azure AD. I want to add redirect URLs using ps script. I tried to take user inputs like,

$uri = Read-Host -Prompt "enter URI"

but this didn't work and threw the following error.

I have no clue what would be the solution for it.

error log=

RunbookFlow : System.Management.Automation.Host.HostException: A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface.ThrowPromptNotInteractive(String promptMessage) at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface.Prompt(String caption, String message, Collection`1 descriptions) at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ReadHostCommand.BeginProcessing() at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoBeginProcessing() at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoBegin() At line:6 char:57 + <#-- Enable activity tracing to see error location --#> RunbookFlow`  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Orchestrator.GraphRunbook.Cmdlets.InvokeRunbookFlowCommand

Comment: Azure sandbox environment doesn't support interactive operations. You can use variables feature to contain your values. Chaning the variables values wouldn't modify any of the runbooks content.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @SwathiDhanwada comment &
As explained in this [Azure Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-execution#runbook-execution-environment), runbook doesn't support interactive operations.

The "Read-Host -prompt" command requires user input. When you run this, it will interrupt the flow and attempt to enter the console mode for user interaction. User interactive operations does not support in Runbooks. As a result, we couldn't use it in the runbook.

*Input and output parameters can be defined using a graphical PowerShell runbook if you want to consider giving it.*

[image]

*I tried prompting in Azure PowerShell and was able to receive prompt as shown:*

```
read-host -prompt "xxx"
```

[image]

**Note**: To invoke read-host in Azure PowerShell, the App needs to be registered under `Azure Active Directory -> App registrations`. Now enable `API Permissions` to read the directory operations to avoid conflicts.

[image]